# How can I set vehicle sensitivity to work for both tanks and jeeps?

Tags: battlefield-3

I have adjusted the in game vehicle sensitivity options so that when controlling a tank the turret moves at a good speed. However, driving a Jeep my look sensitivity is too fast.

Is there a way without using buttons on the mouse to configure the vehicle sensitivity to work for both tanks and Jeeps? If I use the buttons on my mouse, as soon as I exit the vehicle, it affects my foot soldier look sensitivity and I get killed.

Is there external software that would help?

I have a Logitech G9 and I have the setpoint software installed.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one mouse sensitivity setting for the game. Any external software wouldn't know whether you are inside a vehicle and especially inside of which vehicle. Other than DICE implementing this feature I don't think there is an automatic switching of this setting.